# Pager for basic pages in Drupal

Tags: paging

I am working on site, on site for certain set of basic pages i want to provide a numeric navigation with previous/next buttons. Is there a module to achieve it easily or else we need to hard code it.

Please suggest me some solutions to get this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

[Smart Paging](https://drupal.org/project/smart_paging) have the option to navigation with previous/next links with numeric navigation see the below image and add a css style to prev/next class to achieve the button effect. See the [demo](http://www.kapitbisig.com/philippines/bilingual-tagalog-english-version-of-epics-mga-epiko-lam-ang-an-iloko-epic-bilingual-tagalog-english-version_789.html)

[image]

also worth checking this module [Pagerer](https://drupal.org/project/pagerer) for providing a collection of pager themes to enhance Drupal and Views standard pagers. See [Demo](http://mondrake.org/home/pagerer/example)